Big Matrix not available to workers
I am converting a large data frame into a big.matrix object to enable parallel processing (otherwise, the data frame is too large and I run out of RAM). My code is currently like this:
df <- data.frame(
  numeric_col = rnorm(1000),
  factor_col = factor(sample(letters[1:5], 1000, replace = TRUE)),
  char_col = sample(letters[1:5], 1000, replace = TRUE)
)

mat_big <- as.big.matrix(df)


# initialise parallel workers
registerDoParallel(cores = 1)


# parallel loop
outcome <- foreach(i = seq(100),
                   .combine = 'rbind', 
                   .packages = c('bigmemory')) %dopar% {
                     # Attempt to access the big.matrix
                     data <- mat_big[, 1]  # access the first column
                     mean(data)  
                   }

stopImplicitCluster()

I always get Error in unserialize(socklist[[n]]) : error reading from connection. Why? How do I share the big matrix across workers? Thanks.

Looking at the example in help("big.matrix"), you should use describe and attach.big.matrix.


Error in unserialize(socklist[[n]]) : error reading from connection

...means that the master process got an error when calling unserialize to read from the socket connection to one of the workers. That probably means that the corresponding worker died, thus dropping its end of the socket connection. Reasons may vary and are system dependent. Since we don't have access to your PC or the real data, this is all I can do for now.
Try this, it may work for you:

Use desc <- describe(mat_big). The descriptor (desc) of the
big.matrix needs to be explicitly passed to the parallel workers.
Use more cores

The describe() function is used to create a descriptor for the big.matrix. The descriptor is a metadata object that provides information about the big.matrix, such as its size, memory location, and other properties necessary to access the data.
This descriptor is essential for parallel workers to access the data in a distributed manner.
Code:
library(bigmemory)
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)

# library(doSNOW)
# cl <- makeCluster(4, outfile="")
# registerDoSNOW(cl)

df <- data.frame(
  numeric_col = rnorm(1000000),
  factor_col = as.numeric(factor(sample(letters[1:5], 1000000, replace = TRUE))), # Convert factor to numeric
  char_col = as.numeric(factor(sample(letters[1:5], 1000000, replace = TRUE)))   # Convert character to numeric
)

options(timeout = 600)  # Increase timeout to 600 seconds

print(paste0("Cores detected: ", parallel::detectCores())) # use almost every core available

# Convert to big.matrix
mat_big <- as.big.matrix(df)

# Use a descriptor for parallel access
desc <- describe(mat_big)

# Initialize parallel workers
registerDoParallel(cores = parallel::detectCores()-1) # maybe use fewer cores

# Create the descriptor for the big.matrix
desc <- describe(mat_big)

# Parallel loop
outcome <- foreach(i = seq(100),
                   .combine = 'rbind',
                   .packages = c('bigmemory')) %dopar% {
                     mat_big_shared <- attach.big.matrix(desc)  # Attach big.matrix in workers
                     mean(mat_big_shared[, 1])  # Access and compute on the first column
                   }

# Stop parallel cluster
stopImplicitCluster()
outcome

